# Piston Generic Helper process

Tags: python, process

What does the Python script`"piston_generic_helper" do?

It's run-time is taking too much CPU power slowing down the graphics. Maybe a bottleneck.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version you're using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Try [Synaptic package manager](http://packages.ubunut.com/xenial/)

As this Bug report it is from the Ubuntu SW Center and it has always done this type of slowness.

Comment: Which bug report?

Comment: Ther are many bug reports about SW Center taking 100 % cou load - https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=piston_generic_helper+cpu&field.actions.search=Search